# Populating choices from another Models objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-4.0

Quick question, I can not for the life of me figure out how to get this to work and need some help.

**Problem**
I need to be able to query another model's objects to use for choices in a different model. I was thinking about a foreign key but I really do not need it to extend the other model.

I have a group called `Group` that will display choices from another model called  `Games`. These objects will already be saved in the database. I just can't figure out how to display the choices.

***Models.py for the Model we are trying to display the choice in***

`game` is the field we want the choices from the `Games` model

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

from games.models import Games


# Create your models here.

class Group(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Games, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    total_size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    play_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    roles = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_full = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***Models.py from the Model we want to generate the choices from***
I want to use the `name` field from this model for the choices on the `Group` `game` field.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max


# Create your models here.

class Games(models.Model) :
    GENRE_CHOICES = [
        ('Action', 'Action'),
        ('Acion-Adventure', 'Action-Adventure'),
        ('Adventure', 'Adventure'),
        ('MMO', 'MMO'),
        ('Puzzle', 'Puzzle'),
        ('Role Playing', 'Role Playing'),
        ('Simulation', 'Simulation'),
        ('Strategy', 'Strategy'),
        ('Sports', 'Sports')
         ]

    RATING_CHOICES = [
        ('E', 'Everyone'),
        ('E10+', 'Everyone 10+'),
        ('T', 'Teen'),
        ('M', 'Mature 17+'),
        ('A', 'Adults Only 18+'),
        ('RP', 'Rating Pending')
         ]

    PLATFORM_CHOICES = [
        ('Multi', 'Multi Platform'),
        ('PC', 'PC'),
        ('XBOX', 'XBOX'),
        ('Playstation', 'Playstation'),
        ('Nintendo', 'Nintendo')
         ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                null=True,
                                choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES,
                                default='Select'
    )
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                             null=True,
                             choices=GENRE_CHOICES,
                             default='Select'
                             )
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                              null=True,
                              choices=RATING_CHOICES,
                              default='Select'
                              )
    release_date = models.DateField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        max_length=200,
        default='games/default.png',
        null=True,
        upload_to='games/'
    )
    is_new = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    is_popular = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was not in the models.py but in my forms.py I was not defining a ModelChoiceField for this. So in my Forms.py I added this:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Group
        fields = ['name', 'game', 'size', 'total_size', 'play_time', 
                  'description', 'roles']

    game = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Games.objects.all())
```